# Running error with pytorch2.0 compile mode

Tags: pytorch

I am running out of an error with below trace logs. The actual trace logs are very large.

```
 File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/graph.py", line 343, in get_attr
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/fx/interpreter.py", line 136, in run
    self.env[node] = self.run_node(node)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/graph.py", line 407, in run_node
    if value.shape == ():
AttributeError: __torch__.torch.classes.c10d.ProcessGroup (of Python compilation unit at: 0) does not have a field with name 'shape'
While executing %_tensor_constant0 : [#users=1] = get_attr[target=_tensor_constant0]
Original traceback:
None    result = super().run_node(n)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/fx/interpreter.py", line 177, in run_node
    return getattr(self, n.op)(n.target, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_inductor/graph.py", line 343, in get_attr
```

Is there any dependency missing to install ?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet?